# How can I make a calculator ask the user if they want to perform another calculation in Java?

Tags: java, calculator

I have tried to do this using a do while loop however the variable isn't found. My goal is to basically perform the code all over again when the user wants to. Can anybody help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        do{
            Scanner typed=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please type: 1 for add, 2 for subtract, 3 for multiply or 4 for divide");
            int userInput=typed.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the first number to calculate:");
            double number1=typed.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the second number to calculate:");
            double number2=typed.nextDouble();
            if (userInput==1){
                System.out.println("The answer is");
                double result=number1+number2;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            if (userInput==2){
                System.out.println("The answer is");
                double result=number1-number2;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            if (userInput==3){
                System.out.println("The answer is");
                double result=number1*number2;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            if (userInput==4){
                System.out.println("The answer is");
                double result=number1/number2;
                System.out.println(result);
            }
                System.out.println("Do you want to perform another calculation? Press 1 for yes or 2 for no.");
                int pressed=typed.nextInt();
            
        }while(pressed==1);
            
    }
}
```

Comment: "the variable isn't found" -- which variable, on which line?

Comment: Are you referring to `int pressed ` ? It is outside of your do loop.

Comment: Try putting `int pressed = 1;` before `do {`.

Comment: As a word of advice too, whenever you are thinking "I have a whole bunch of this code I want to loop over!"  It might be worth thinking about putting that code into a method, and loop around the method.  It makes it much easier to read the code, and easier to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable outside of its scope.

```
    do{
      // ...
      int pressed=typed.nextInt();
        
    }while(pressed==1);  // Outside of the scope of 'pressed'
```

You can address this by moving the declaration outside the loop, but leaving the assignment.

```
    int pressed = 1;

    do{
      // ...
      pressed=typed.nextInt();
        
    }while(pressed==1);  // Outside of the scope of 'pressed'
```

Answer (score 1):

`pressed` leaves *scope* after the body of your loop. Move the declaration of `pressed` to before the `do`.

```
int pressed = 0;
do {
    // ...
    pressed=typed.nextInt();
} while(pressed==1);
```

**Or**, you could change your loop to an infinite loop `while(true);` and use

```
int pressed = typed.nextInt();
if (pressed != 1) {
    break; // End the infinite loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare 'pressed' variable outside the do while loop.

```
int pressed;
do 
{
 //code
}
```

and remove int from
`int pressed=typed.nextInt();` this line
so that it becomes `pressed=typed.nextInt();`

Comment: You keep your answer to compact. If the poster already uses code, then why are you not using it too? Copy the code block you would edit and change it obviously. 
Reading instruction on how to change the block is very hard and inefficient. You rather make more explicit comments, then readers will appreciate it more :) 
Also try using styling. For code use a code block to separate text from code, and take use of italics and bold when you want to highlight things (example: using variables in your explanation)

Comment: Thanks, I am new to stackoverflow so not quite efficient with formatting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No worries. That is why I try to help you ;) I would suggest to edit the answer.